# iOS Simulator not rotating for iPhone (working for iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

When I rotate a virtual **iPad** device to landscape in the iOS simulator, the device rotates and the iOS UI (the home screen) rotates to match the physical orientation, as expected.

If I rotate a virtual **iPhone**, the device rotates but the UI doesn't rotate, which seems wrong. It's as if I have the orientation locked in the settings, but this isn't set.

- iOS Simulator 7.0 (463.9.4.2)
- iOS version on simulator is 7.0.3 (11B508)
- OS X version 10.9.1

I have tried deleting the application support folder, with no effect.

Does anyone know what else I can try to fix this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems wrong? This is standard behavior of real iPhones. The home screen has never supported any orientation other than portrait, at least not without the aide of jailbreak tweaks.

Comment: The iPhone 6/7 Plus phones supported a landscape home screen, but they have moved back away from that on newer phones.